# Синтаксис сеттеров в Ruby

Tags: ruby, setter, brackets

Нужны ли скобки в сеттере? Или можно использовать var=str? Работать то будут оба варианта, но везде почему-то встречается вариант со скобками.
Про то, что можно использовать attr_writer не говорите, это итак понятно.

```
class SomeClass
  def var=(str)
    @var = str
  end

  def var
    @var
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby-разработчики стараются придерживаться определенных правил оформления кода. Вы не указываете точку с запятой в конце выражения, хотя это допускается. Вы не указываете оператор `return` в последнем выражении метода, хотя это допускается.

В отношении скобок, обрамляющих параметры методов так же существует правило:

> Используйте `def` со скобками, когда у метода есть параметры. Опускайте
>   скобки, когда метод не принимает параметров.

```
# плохо
def some_method()
 # некоторый код
end

# хорошо
def some_method
 # некоторый код
end

# плохо
def some_method_with_parameters param1, param2
 # некоторый код
end

# хорошо
def some_method_with_parameters(param1, param2)
 # некоторый код
end
```

Более подробно с правилами оформления кода можно ознакомиться [тут](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide). Именно поэтому вы видите везде сеттер со скобками - это признак хорошего кода в Ruby.

Comment: Хорошие программисты придерживаются правил, подходящих к проекту, а не того вредного бреда от ббатсова.

Comment: @Nakilon Ну тем не менее можно придти на проект, к которому прикручен rubocop и ваши реквесты могут просто не рассматриваться, если тесты rubocop не прошли на CI. Это объективная реальность. А теперь угадайте, что за правила там и часто ли их меняют под проект?

Comment: Нафиг-нафиг такие проекты.